# Vue detect click on other component

Tags: vue.js

I have a table and on each row I have a column that display an ellipsis menu, meaning as you can guess that the component is render many times.

So now I want to close the menu when the user click outside or in other of the ellipsis menus. I have found the answer for clicking outside but if I click on the ellipsis component of another row the previous opened remains open.

Why the click outside does not recognise that there is more than 1 component? I have tried adding keys to them but still does not work:

Here is my component:

```
<template>
    <div class="ellipsis-menu" v-click-outside="hide">
        <button class="ellipsis" @click.stop="show = !show"></button>
        <ul v-show="show">
            <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.title">
                <a @click.stop :href="item.action" class="btn-block">{{ item.title }} <span v-html="item.icon"></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import ClickOutside from 'vue-click-outside'

export default {
    props: {
        items: {
            default: function() {

            },
            type: Array
        }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            show: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        hide() {
            this.show = false
        }
    },
    directives: {
        ClickOutside
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe because you've got `@click.stop` instead of just `@click`. If you stop propagation of the click event, the click outside directive cannot handle the click event.

Comment: @DecadeMoon yeah you are right, its a problem because I need that stop! but I will find a work around! thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you also want to close the menu when a user tab's outside of the ellipsis menu's too, right? (Think of accessibility and keyboard only users.) You should look into `vue-outside-events` where you can target tabbing outside as well...  https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-outside-events

Comment: @maxshuty thanks mate, I will take a deeper look